# How to define non-member operator overload for class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, c++14

I have a class template that has a constructor taking an std::chrono::duration, because I want to be able to use the chrono_literals to construct it. Now, I'm trying to define a non-member operator overload but I can't get it to work with the duration constructor:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int n> struct MyClass {
  MyClass() = default;

  template <typename REP, typename PERIOD>
  constexpr MyClass(const std::chrono::duration<REP, PERIOD> &d) noexcept
      : num(d.count()) {}

  int num = n;
};

template <int n> bool operator==(MyClass<n> lhs, MyClass<n> rhs) {
  return lhs.num == rhs.num;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

  MyClass<0> m1(10ns);

  if (m1 == 10ns)
    cout << "Yay!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

gcc is giving this error for rejecting my overload:

```
main.cpp:34:12: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘MyClass<0>’ and ‘std::chrono::nanoseconds {aka std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >}’)
     if (m1 == 10ns)
         ~~~^~~~~~~
main.cpp:23:6: note: candidate: template<int n> bool operator==(MyClass<n>, MyClass<n>)
 bool operator == (MyClass<n> lhs, MyClass<n> rhs)
      ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:23:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:34:15: note:   ‘std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >’ is not derived from ‘MyClass<n>’
     if (m1 == 10ns)
               ^~~~
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: This would need a specific combination of template deduction, user defined conversion, and overload resolution. And they don't happen in the order this code would require.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simpler way is to put the function in the class:

```
template <int n> struct MyClass {
  MyClass() = default;

  template <typename REP, typename PERIOD>
  constexpr MyClass(const std::chrono::duration<REP, PERIOD> &d) noexcept
      : num(d.count()) {}

    friend bool operator==(MyClass lhs, MyClass rhs) { return lhs.num == rhs.num; }


  int num = n;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c48546ae48e44f)

Comment: That's a good solution, thanks! What if I don't want the function to: 1. be declared friend, 2. be defined inside the class definition? I guess I'm asking, is this the "simpler" way or the _only_ way?

Comment: @dcmm88 By definition, a friend function is a non-member function, just as if you declared it outside the class. And as a bonus, you can do what you want with *your* class, including accessing private members. There is no downside of using a friend in this case. You could however define the friend function outside the class, but you will still have to declare it inside.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I don't think that actually works (declaring inside and defining outside). How would I define it outside, with a template? Then I'm back to the original issue, no?

Comment: @dcmm88 indeed, defining friends outside is not as easy as simply writing the function inside the class. As Barry stated, there is other solutions, but the simplest one is defining the friend.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't work:

```
if (m1 == 10ns)
```

because when we're doing lookup on `operator==` between `MyClass<0>` and `std::chrono::duration<???, std::nano>`, the only operator we find is:

```
template <int n>
bool operator==(MyClass<n> lhs, MyClass<n> rhs);
```

This isn't a match - `10ns` is not a `MyClass<n>` for any `n`, so template deduction fails. To write a non-member equality operator, you would need to match against *any* duration:

```
template <int n, class R, class P> bool operator==(MyClass<n>, duration<R,P> );
```

in both directions:

```
template <int n, class R, class P> bool operator==(duration<R,P>, MyClass<n> );
```

In addition to the operator you already have. That would work, and is sometimes even necessary.

A simpler approach would be to declare your `operator==` as non-member friend, as [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42764771/2069064) suggests. The reason this works is that where your non-member function was a function template, the friend is *not*. So lookup on `m1 == 10ns` finds the function:

```
bool operator==(MyClass<0>, MyClass<0>);
```

`10ns` is convertible to `MyClass<0>`, which is allowed in this context, so this works. That conversion is very cheap, so no worries there. And you just have to write the one function.

Comment: Or wrap one of the two parameters in a non-deduced context.

Comment: @T.C.: Would it be problematic in C++20 with [rewritten candidates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator)?